# IE loses his lef & right hand on RTL pages

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to do some round corners work with IE 9 :-(
This is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body{
                direction:rtl;
            }
            ul{
                list-style: none outside none;
                padding:0px;
            }
            li{
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
                border: 1px solid #777;
                background-color: #AAA;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='some'>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test2</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just because of `direction:rtl;` on body IE loses his left & right hand!
Border is rounded correctly & background is mirrored like image below

[image: IE is an absolute idiot and this picture is one prove on it in millions]

it seems it thinks right hand of RTL people is their left hand X-(
Firefox, Chrome, Safari , ... has no problem and render it correctly;
Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: A quick workaround is to apply direction:ltr to your li style. Or create a new class only for your buttons and apply direction:ltr in case you need the direction to remain rtl for others lists items.

Comment: @Dane: yes this works but if I mix RTL & LTR (or symbols) text in it then it will mess up!!

Comment: Whenever I want to design a RTL website I never apply direction:rtl to the body. I only apply it to the elements I explicitly need them. (e.g. Main Content, text labels of menu items). Hope this help

Comment: @Dane: this is in the case you only need to display text correctly; but if you need every thing switch right; (menus open from right to left and other things ) you need to apply it on body; otherwise you have a LTR page that displays RTL text correctly but not a full RTL page!

Comment: I stumbled upon this question when I had a similar problem, but it turned out it was CSS PIE that was causing the unusual flip.  I added `css3-container { direction: ltr !important; }` to my CSS and it solved that issue [Forum Topic](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=305)

Comment: I also found that borders get flipped in < IE10, but it will not show up in the Emulators - only the actual IE9, IE8, IE7, etc. browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Updated answer with solution below

http://jsfiddle.net/hxSgH/

```
        body{
        direction:rtl;
        }

        ul{
            direction:ltr;
            list-style: none outside none;
            padding:0px;
        }

        li{
            direction:rtl;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
            border: 1px solid #777;
            background-color: #FF0000;
        }

<body>
     <ul id='some'>
        <li>test1 میکنیم @</li>
        <li>test2 میکنیم @</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks; but as i said in answer to Dane's comment: yes this works but if I mix RTL & LTR (or symbols) text in it then it will mess up!! Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/dNeK8/1/ (the one that has `test1` is correct)

Comment: it is the same code! but it seems it is a IE bug and I need to use pure RTL or LTR text until those people in Micro$soft fix it; thanks